# Jquery: extending array within each loop

Tags: jquery

I'm filtering a an array in Jquery depending of some button selections of the user. I loop over the possibilities and build a "result" array extending it with a "original_array" slice.

```
result = []
$.each(university_selection, function(index, value) {
     if ($(value).attr('name') == 'on') {
          partial = jQuery.grep(original_array, function(n) { return ( n.institucion == $(value).text()); });
          result = $.extend( result , partial )
     };
});
```

The filterign works fine, but the "extend" command seems to replace previous instance instead of "accumulating". I only get the last slice returned.

I guess it has something to do with the moment in which the "result = $.extend( result , partial )" is stored in memory.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

To tweak your jQuery, you can push each item in `partial` to `result`:

```
result.push(...partial);
```

or

```
result = result.concat(partial)
```

But the overall code is kinda verbose, not very functional, and more computationally complex than it needs to be.

To reduce the computational complexity from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`, construct a Set of the `on` values, then `.filter` the `original_array` by whether the `institucion` property is included. The logic will probably be a lot clearer to follow as well:

```
const selectedValues = new Set(
  [...university_selection]
    .filter(elm => elm.name === 'on')
    .map(elm => elm.textContent)
);
const result = original_array.filter(item => selectedValues.has(item.institucion));
```

This way, you only iterate over the `original_array` once, and a plain `.filter` constructs the `result` array based on a simple condition.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue using

```
result = result.concat( partial );
```